# android ndk (opencv)

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I got a crash when i call my native functions in my android application here is my code :

```
lib libo=new lib();
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{
    int s;// where w and h are width and height are the parameters of the camera
    s=libo.getdata(data);/: and getdata is my native function
}
```

my getdata.c :

```
#include "getdata.h"
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL JAVA_android_video8_libo_som
(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,jbyte* data)
{
    return (data[1]);
}
```

getdata.h :

```
#include <jni.h>


#ifndef _Included_android_video8_lib
#define _Included_android_video8_lib
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT int JNICALL JAVA_android_video8_libo_som(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jbyte*);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := opcv
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := getdata.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and the class where i call the lib :

```
package android.video8;

public class libo { 
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("opcv");
            }
        public native static  int som(int s);
}
```

the library is generated without a problem but the exécution of the apps give me a crash
i don't no where ehe error is
 thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Seems there're some errors in your question. Anyway, you're using wrong prototypes for JNI functions. You should use these signatures:

```
JNIEXPORT
jint JNICALL JAVA_android_video8_libo_getData(JNIEnv*, jclass, jbyteArray);

JNIEXPORT
jint JNICALL JAVA_android_video8_libo_som(JNIEnv*, jclass, jint);
```

And use **javah** tool every time you change native method's prototype.